# Pausing threads from processing queues in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading

Say I have a class `Talker`.  I'm using a queue to make the Talker talk, but I occasionally want to mute the talker, but when I unmute the talker, I want the talker to pickup where he left off.  How do I stop the threads from taking messages from the queue and wait until I unmute the talker to resume?

```
class Talker
  def initialize
    @queue = Queue.new
    @threads = Array.new(1) do
      Thread.new do
        until @queue.empty?
          # what logic should go here to check if mute
          # and stop taking messages?
          next_msg = @queue.shift

          puts next_msg
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def speak(msg)
    @queue.push(msg)
  end

  # stop threads from taking messages from queue
  def mute
    # what goes here?
  end

  # allow threads to continuing taking messages from queue
  def unmute
    # what goes here?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Though ruby is definitely not the best choice for handling async operations, one still may make use of [`Thread::Mutex`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Thread/Mutex.html):

```
@handler = Class.new do
  @locks = {}

  def mute(id, mutex)
    @locks[id] ||= mutex.lock
  end

  def unmute(id)
    @locks[id].unlock if @locks[id].is_a?(Thread::Mutex)
    @locks.delete(id)
  end
end


Thread.new do
  MX = Thread::Mutex.new
  until @queue.empty?
    MX.synchronize do
      next_msg = @queue.shift
      puts next_msg
    end
  end
end

# stop threads from taking messages from queue
def mute
  @handler.mute(self, MX)
end

# allow threads to continuing taking messages from queue
def unmute
  @handler.unmute(self)
end
```

The code is untested, but I believe it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having a mutex per thread, you could have a simple flag protected by a mutex

```
class Talker
  def initialize
    @muted = false
    @muted_mutex = Thread::Mutex.new

    @queue = Queue.new
    @threads = Array.new(1) do
      Thread.new do
        until @queue.empty?
          next if @muted # skip this iteration
          puts @queue.shift
        end
      end
    end
  end

  def mute
    @muted_mutex.synchronize { @muted = true }
  end

  def unmute
    @muted_mutex.synchronize { @muted = false }
  end
end
```

The difference between this and having a mutex per-thread is that this will only block if multiple threads (elsewhere) try to mute/unmute simultaneously. However there also might be a slight delay between muting and the threads actually stopping since there's a race between setting `@muted = false` and the thread reading it.

It's probably not considered good practice, but if I were you I would even ditch the mutex. For a Boolean flag it makes no difference if there are multiple writes occurring simultaneously.